# Solr: ordering by a multi valued field

Tags: solr, multivalue

I need to create a new collection on my **Solr 6.1.0** cluster where every row is a **content** and every content can belong to one or many categories, which are specified in a multivalued field **categories**.

In my web app the user can search by categories, and if wanted it can even group results by category. If it wants to order by category, what about the contents which belong to more than one category?

In this case, the search results page should show the same content more times in different categories. I don't want the web application to filter and order results because in this case, it should ask Solr for every row (I know this is not advised for bad performance), so is there a way to let Solr make this? For example, repeating the same content in two categories if a flag is enabled or if I am asking Solr to sort by category?

Until now I bypassed the problem cloning one record for every category and specifying the category ID in a single int field. But this is not optimized, because in this case my index is much bigger than it could be, and every content metadata a part of **category** is just the same for every content, and because of this I would like to have 1 content = 1 Solr record.

Comment: 1) Repeating the content may not be so bad from the perspective of NoSQL databases. How much your index is got bigger?
2) Does result grouping help for you?

Comment: My index is now about 7 million rows and about 65Gb of disk space. If I could deduplicate data it could be half